# Why is blockquote not showing up in my source after parsing quote tag?

Tags: php, bbcode, quote

I am developing a custom forum with CodeIgniter.  I need to create a function that parses [quote] tags.  I want my function to pass the id of the quoted post as well as the original message.  For some reason, the blockquote tags are not showing up in my source, however, the original message is. Can someone tell me why?

```
   <?php

function parse_bb($str){

        $str = nl2br($str);

        $find = array(
            "'\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]'is",
            "'\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]'is",
            "'\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]'is",
            "'\[s\](.*?)\[/s\]'is",
            "'\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]'is",
            "'\[url\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
            "'\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]'i",
            "'\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
            "'\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/link\]'i",
            "'\[h1\](.*?)\[\/h1\]'is",
            "'\[h2\](.*?)\[\/h2\]'is",
            "'\[h3\](.*?)\[\/h3\]'is",
            "'\[ul\](.*?)\[\/ul\]'is",
            "'\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]'is",
            "'\[p\](.*?)\[\/p\]'is",
            "'\[quote id=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]'is"
        );

        $replace = array(
            '<strong>\1</strong>',
            '<em>\1</em>',
            '<u>\1</u>',
            '<s>\1</s>',
            '<img src="\1" \1alt="User Image" />',
            '<a href="\1">\1</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\1</a>',
            '<a href="\1">\2</a>',
            '<h1>\1</h1>',
            '<h2>\1</h2>',
            '<h3>\1</h3>',
            '<ul>\1</ul>',
            '<li>\1</li>',
            '<p>\1</p>',
            _parse_quote($post_id = "\1", $original_message = "\2")
        );

        $str = preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);



        return $str;

    }

function _parse_quote($post_id, $original_message){

        $str = $post_id;

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $CI->load->model('forums/message');

        $CI->message->get_info($post_id);

        if($CI->message->error == NULL){

                $message = $CI->message->info;

                $str = 'Message Id '.$post_id.'
                        <blockquote>
                                <p>'.$original_message.'</p>
                        </blockquote>
                        ';

        } else {

                $str .= $CI->message->error;

        }

        return $str;
}
```

Comment: The p tags are not showing up in the source, either.

Comment: Done any debugging yourself? Checked if your _parse_quote() function is even being called? that the proper parameters are coming through? That the $CI calls are actually getting something and the `<blockquote>` code is being called? We're not going to read through a wall of text and GUESS at what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, so the function is being called, but the parameters are not being passed correctly.  I did a test and both $post_id and $original_message return blank.

Comment: I changed the code in my original question.

Comment: For this to work, you'd need either `preg_replace_callback`, or the `/e`  modifier, with the code as string (the horror...). Right now you are just storing a fixed string from the reurn of `_parse_quote` in there with the _literal_ `\1` & `\2` as parameters. Normal `preg_replace` doesn't do callbacks (and if it would, this would still fail because of the already stated reason). On a side note: [bbcode handling is available as a PECL extension.. which would save time..](http://www.php.net/manual/en/bbcode.setup.php)